# using kind_of? with Rspec in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

Im trying to test this method, the method can just take integers as parameters but I can't make it work; unfortunately. 
Thanks for yr time.
I dont understand this error-log:

1) DownloadingData interval_data takes 2 integers as parameters to set up the time-interval
     Failure/Error: bag.should_receive(:interval_data).with(2, kind_of(Numeric), kind_of?(Numeric), 2)
       (#).interval_data(2, #, false, 2)
           expected: 1 time with arguments: (2, #, false, 2)
           received: 0 times with arguments: (2, #, false, 2)

My code:

```
class DownloadingData

  attr_accessor :today

  def initialize
    @today = Date.today
  end

  def interval_data(point_a, point_b)
    start_point = @today - point_a
    end_point  = @today + point_b
    (start_point..end_point).each do |week_day|
      puts week_day #checking the week day
    end
  end
end
```

My test:

```
describe DownloadingData do
   let(:bag) { DownloadingData.new }

  describe 'interval_data' do
    it 'responds to interval_data' do
      expect(bag).to respond_to(:interval_data)
    end
    it 'takes 2 integers as parameters to set up the time-interval' do
      bag.should_receive(:interval_data).with(2, kind_of(Numeric), kind_of?(Numeric), 2)
    end
end
```

Comment: You probably don't want to use should_receive here. Instead call the method and specify what the return value should be (or what side effects should have occurred)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have to actually use the method after statintg that it should be received, or it will not be received. `receive` checks if a method was actually used with a stub. Thats why he states he received 0 times. [RSPEC expect message](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-1/docs/basics/expecting-messages)

Here you can see how with can be used: [matching arguments](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-1/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments)

Try this:

```
it 'takes 2 integers as parameters to set up the time-interval' do
  expect(bag).to receive(:interval_data).with(kind_of(Numeric), kind_of(Numeric)).and_call_original
  bag.interval_data(1, 2)
end
```

though this will only validate that calling your method with 2 Numerics won't cause an exception.

Comment: Although that spec doesn't really do anything

Comment: well it validates that the interval_data method runs without errors with 2 numerics. Not really necessary to test it like that, but thats what was asked for.

Comment: @ascar Hi there! thanks for th reply! u said: "Not really necessary to test it like that" how would it be tested then? Thanks!

Comment: testing correct kind of input only makes sense if this method is called dynamically from within another method and you want to make sure code works if that other method is changed. My provided spec will always work if the method does not throw an exception as i explcitily provide working input during the spec. expect{bag.interval_data(1, 2)}.not_to raise_error would do the same thing.

Comment: @ascar the method call is stubbed out by the use of `receive` - the original implementation isn't tested

Comment: @FrederickCheung oh yeah thats true. kind of pointless testing it like that. i added and_call_original so it at least ensures the method runs with that arguments :D

Comment: I hear you guys  what you're saying! Thanks for the comments  lol I  was maybe a bit tired; yesterday. Reading your comments I noticed my error: It wasn't about testing numeric values but integer values, actually. In the other hand @ascar, u put on the right path about writing Stubs! Thanks!

Comment: @FrederickCheung ohh I see now what you're saying about this: " - the original implementation isn't tested – " yes I might need to set up a if-statement to check for my requirement: just Integer-values oops! :)